eureu phpmail Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
hello I know error that I cannot resolve this eueu
2024-12-14 17:48:11 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2024-12-14 17:48:11 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Erreur lors de l'envoi du message : SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
and I want to avoid using a relay
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);

 require 'PHPMailer-6.6.0/src/PHPMailer.php'; 
require 'PHPMailer-6.6.0/src/SMTP.php'; 
require 'PHPMailer-6.6.0/src/Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try { 
$mail->isSMTP();
 $mail->Host = 'domainname.org'; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->Debugoutput = 'echo'; 
 $mail->SMTPOptions = array( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true ) );       

$mail->Username = 'contact@domainname.org'; 
$mail->Password = 'MonMotDePasse123';
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS; activé
$mail->Port = 587;


$mail->setFrom('contact@domainname.org', 'Mon Site Web');
$mail->addAddress('desinatair@outlook.fr', 'Nom Destinataire');
$mail->addReplyTo('contact@domainname.org', 'Support VEX');


$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Sujet de l\'email';
$mail->Body = '<h1>Ceci est un test</h1><p>Message envoyé depuis domainname.org.</p>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Ceci est un test. Message envoyé depuis domainname.org.';


$mail->send();
echo 'Message envoyé avec succès !';} catch (Exception $e) {echo "Erreur lors de l'envoi du message : {$mail->ErrorInfo}";}?>`

and Port 25,587 are open and in the firewall
under debian
telnet ``domainname``org 587 Trying ip.ip.ip.180... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused root@raspberrypi:~#
I configured the MX Record on noip and I looked for the Internet service provider but it does not seem to put a retission
root@raspberrypi:~# telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6c... Connected to smtp.gmail.com. Escape character is '^]'. 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ffacd0b85a97d-388c8016326sm8340120f8f.34 - gsmt
thanks in advance

Is "domainname.org" the correct mail host? Search where your provider (of domainname.org) has its SMTP server.

As the error message says, which is also confirmed by your telnet test, your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP. You need to contact them and ask for the port to be opened (it isn’t a problem with your firewall, which is only handling inbound connections), or find a better provider. This is covered extensively in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.

I configured the MX Record on noip and I looked for the Internet service provider but it does not seem to put a retission  root@raspberrypi:~# telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6c... Connected to smtp.gmail.com. Escape character is '^]'. 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ffacd0b85a97d-388c8016326sm8340120f8f.34 - gsmtpbut nothing still set error

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it
